# Como concatenar uma variável no ActionScript 3?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, animate

Olá, tenho uma lista de movie clips para serem chamados dentro de um if, mas não estou conseguindo concatenar a variável que contém o nome destes movies. Imagine que:

Tenho três movie clips: p1, p2 e p3. E quero chama-los dinamicamente, tentei assim mas não funciona. Alguém sabe como?

```
if (qtdd == variavel_num) {

    this."caminho_do_mc.p" + var_numero_do_mc + .gotoAndStop(2); //o problema está aqui

    }
```

Comment: Você pode tentar assim `this["caminho_do_mc.p"+var_numero_do_mc].gotoAndStop(2);`  ou assim `this.caminho_do_mc["p"+var_numero_do_mc].gotoAndStop(2)`

Comment: Passa o código de declaração dos clips.

Comment: Tentei deste jeito Ícaro mas não funcionou :( 

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Antes disso assuma que `this is DisplayObjectContainer`. No geral você pode tentar:

```
MovieClip(this.getChildByName('p'+ n)).gotoAndPlay(2)
// assumindo que ` mc_1.name = 'p1' `
```

(Usar listas além de containers é algo extra.)

Ou pode usar o método [container.getChildAt()](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt()): (dependendo do caso!)

```
(this.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(2) // mc_1

// ou usando n (0, 2)

(this.getChildAt(n) as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(2) // mc_1
```

Lembrando de importar as definições:

```
import flash.display.*
```